# java.awt.Robot is unable to paste long strings

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot

I use `Robot` class to paste strings from clipboard to file chooser dialog window in a loop. Strings are file paths, so these are 100-180 characters long. After the first few strings it is unable to paste more. The same solution is working well with shorter strings.

```
StringSelection ssss = new StringSelection(fileSource);
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ssss, null);
Robot probot = new Robot();
probot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
Thread.sleep(2000);
probot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
Thread.sleep(2000);
probot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
Thread.sleep(2000);
probot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
Thread.sleep(2000);
probot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
probot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use `textField.setText()`?

Comment: @GeorgeZ. : I can use `sendKeys()` method for this element, value is sent, but it isn't interpreted as a valid file, so it will not be uploaded.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] in order to show us what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Robot sounds like a bad choice for something like that (If I understand correctly what you are asking here). During the `Thread.sleep(2000)`, if user changes window Robot will paste it to another window.

Comment: @GeorgeZ. : It is executed on a separated machine, so that is not a problem. Here is an example: https://tus.io/demo.html , but any other sites, which open a file chooser dialog window are a good example.